# online/cloud video encoding for website

Tags: cloud, video-encoding, video-player

users will load up videos from ios app, android app and vía webupload to my server.
so i get a lot of different video formats, which i need to encode for showing them in the website.
As we now, video encoding is not a simple thing. I´m doing it up to now on the webserver itself, using ffmpeg with php. That was ok for the Beta Version, but now i need a professional service. The encoding takes a lot of server cpu time and trying to cover all the video formats is practically imposible for me.

From what i found out up to now, the most profesional solution seems to be a online/cloud service like like transloadit.com, or zencoder.com or encoding.com. There are more, but that's what o foung up to now.

Does anyone have experience with these or other similar services and can tell something about the advantages and disadvantages of each of them?

I also consider using Amazon S3 bucket to save the uploaded videos. Some (or all) of the named services, deliver the encoded videos also to a S3 bucket if wanted.

And last but not least i'd like to get also some help in which player is recommended to use. The videos will be called from desktop, tablets and smartphones vía a web app.
The alternatives i see up to now are jwplayer.com, flowplayer.org and vid.ly player.

Answer (score 1):

One very highlevel third party service which I used in the past if Wistia.com. They have APIs to upload videos (most format, I guess) to them. Once you upload, you need to wait for them to be transcoded and ready to be streamed - You can check this status via API again. Then you will get an HTML embed code (as from youtube), using which you can stream the videos on your website. This basically abstracts lot of things for you (no need to deal with jwplayer, transcoder etc)

Hoeever, You can use AWS elastic transcoder for transcoding if you want to do it the developer way. You should be able to call the APIs from anywhere (even from your web-server). You can configure S3 such that your users can directly upload to S3, Transcoder picks it from S3, converts and puts it back in S3 again.

[API Reference - Amazon Elastic Transcoder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/api-reference.html)

[This example helps you setup a video trans-coding pipeline.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)

Comment: Sony, thanks for your help. Especialy Amazon Elastic Transcoder. I will have to process many videos, so i think thats an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://www.bitcodin.com as cloud-based transcoding service, which can be used via an API to automate processes. There is a full tutorial on the usage together with Amazon S3 and CloudFront: http://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/02/create-mpeg-dash-hls-content-for-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

Answer (score 0):

I have used both amazon's elastic_encoder and zencoder.com both if them are great I personally would prefer zencoder.com which is efficient and much faster but its cons are that it is costlier. As you have mentioned that you are using amazons s3 bucket for uploading video then it is worth mentioning that amazons elastic transcoder works smoothly with s3 and is lot cheaper then zencoder. Moreover zencoder supports more video formats than elasctic trancoder. At work I am using elastic transcoder as primary trascoding but when it fails I user zencoder.com for most part elastic transcoder should do fine. For implementation of [aws elastic encoder](http://aameer.github.io/articles/aws-elastic-encoder/)  (django and python stack) and this post which explains implementation for [zencoder](http://aameer.github.io/articles/encoding-with-zencoder/).Hope it helps.